# Why do barbarian (AT soldier Units) spawn on City States?

Tags: civilization-6

Preslav is a militaristic city state. (not sure if that matters)

Now and again I notice a couple of barbarian AT soldier units?

What is happening? I have noticed these two units popping up and causing troubles from other directions and assume it is the same I noticed here.

The turn before I added envoys and equaled the highest which is France. So no suzerain. Not sure if that matters also.

Turn before:
[image]

Turn After
[image]

Comment: Just a theory: In Civ5 low happiness caused modern-tech barbarians to spawn. But I believe this din't happen to city states. Maybe this behavior changed?

Comment: @Nijin22 Happiness was removed for civ 6. At least on the player end of things. I doubt they kept it in for city states.

Comment: @dustyjuicebox Correct, but they introduced amenities which serve a similar purpose. I also read a message in-game about low amenities causing revolutions (or something similar) to appear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible the city state has low Amenities, and has had a Rebellion.

When I had several low amenity cities in my empire I suffered a rebellion, in which current era barbarian units (in my case it was Field Cannon and Musketmen) appeared around the city.

I cannot confirm this mechanic applies to City States, but I have definitely had it happen to my cities.